# PaypalAPI error on Prestashop

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I'm testing my PayPalAPI module on Prestashop 1.2.x in sandbox mode.

But I have this error:

> ```
> PayPal response:
> TIMESTAMP -> 2012-02-20T18:38:37Z
> L_ERRORCODE0 -> 10002
> L_SHORTMESSAGE0 -> Security error
> L_LONGMESSAGE0 -> Security header is not valid
> L_SEVERITYCODE0 -> Error
> PayPal ha devuelto un error
> ```

I read on sites that the solution is to put offline sandbox mode, If I do this works correctly to the first step of payment on PayPal site...

but how can I do to test Paypal payment??... thanks

Answer (score 7):

I know that it might be late (your message is 3 month old ^^), but I'll answer anyway.

This issue have only three possibilities :

- You have sandbox mode enabled (it seems it's not the case)
- You are using sandbox credential in production mode
- You copy/past wrongly your credentials (adding space, one character missing, ...)

I help a lot of people on this issue, and it's **always** one of this three cases :)

Fabien

Comment: Awesome brother... helped me loads during a time critical project!

Comment: @Flyphp I have sandbox enabled and use a sandbox Paypal account. I am redirected to the PayPal site (it doesn't if I use wrong credentials), but I when I'm at the Paypal Sandbox site, I always get an error and I'm not possible to process my order. I checked that the country settings and email settings throughout the website are identital to those of the PayPal test account, but I can't get it to work.